# deselecting a checkedlistbox value

Tags: c#, winforms, checklistbox

I have a `checklistbox` that has values such as `Value 1, Value 2, Value 3`. If a user checks "Value 1" then the `Label1` will change it's name to "Value 1" and `TextBox1` will be enabled. However, I do not know how to check if the selected value has been deselected. If user deselects a value then `Label1` will change from "Value 1" to "Label1" and `TextBox1` will be disabled. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you share could? I think it can be done by using SelectedIndexChanged event of CheckListBox Control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to event `ItemCheck` it is raised when item is checked/unchecked:

```
private void CheckedListBoxItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    var value = checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString();

    if (value == "Value 1" && e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Value 1";
        Textbox1.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        //disable
        Label1.Text = "Label 1";
        Textbox1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom code to an `ItemCheck` event handler:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show(e.NewValue.ToString());
}
```

Comment: @deepz you are welcome! I admire girls who work as programmers :)